# Getting Google+ Domain API to work in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-plus, google-domain-api

I have read loads of good documentation and example for getting external API's to work in Google Apps Script and also access Google API's with OAuth and have successfully integrated them. I can't however find any help with getting the Google+ Domains API https://developers.google.com/+/domains/ working in GAS.

I understand its a little different as it has the capability to do domain wide delegation of authority (which is what I want).

If anyone can help point me in the right direction that would be great.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a short sample code for the Google+ Domains API with Apps Script.
Please see the gist below.
https://gist.github.com/soundTricker/7130533

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your post, nice little script however I was looking for something that used the domain wide delegation functionality. You script is great for reading and for writing posts to your own stream but what if you want to connect to another account within your domain ? Domain wide delegation is explained more here https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but it's not possible to edit data on other users in the domain with the "Google+ Domains Service"

It tells you in the second part on the first page:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/plus-domains

"This service doesn't support the domain-wide delegation feature in the underlying API. This means that domain **admininstrators are not able to run a script on behalf of users in their domain**."

This is really sad, it would have been so nice if it was possible! Please G00glez fix this =)